# Can't run Anaconda from command line (or anywhere else)

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, python-3.6

I am running Windows 10 with Anaconda 3. I attempted to get to the Anaconda Navigator through clicking on navigator app in Explorer (Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-navigator-1.8.7-py36_0) but that only brings up a flash of what I assume is the command window (because it's too fast to see) and then nothing happens.

I can use the Anaconda prompt and so I tried running navigator using 'anaconda-navigator' and it gives error line:

```
".....is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."
```

I tried typing 'jupyter notebook' into the command line but the message is:

```
Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 'jupyter-notebook' not found] 2
```

This has happened multiple times with me uninstalling and reinstalling Anaconda. How do I fix this as it seems to be a serious problem as almost nothing works?

Answer (score 1):

To run anaconda-navigator:

```
$ source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate root
$ anaconda-navigator
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters I would check the environment path.
if you go in the application folder, where the exe or run program is, can you start it?
Is there a bin folder? See if you can start Anaconda in debug mode.

this might help: http://anaconda-installer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/boot-options.html

Comment: nothing associated with anaconda works despite the fact that it is installed, I always get something like:
"'inst.rescue' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: I already tried running anaconda navigator from the exe program but that didn't do anything (it creates a flash of a command window and then does nothing)

Comment: That flash is usually where some error message comes and tells you what's wrong. Running anaconda in debug mode will hold the "flash" so one can read.

Comment: How do I run it in debug mode if I can't run it at all? Despite the installer telling me that it was successful, and Anaconda Prompt still working, I can't run anything from the Anaconda Prompt at all. Every command results in the same message: "{any command} is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Answer (score 0):

I would first look to see whether `anaconda-navigator` and `jupyter-notebook` are installed in your environment through the command `conda list` at your anaconda prompt.

If they are missing just install them through `conda install anaconda-navigator jupyter-notebook`

Generally, i would execute the command `conda install anaconda anaconda-navigator jupyter ipython` just to be sure that no packages are missing from your environment.

Hope this helped. :)